# SOQL To Get Account fields associated with an Opportunity Contact Role to Opportunity Object

Tags: soql, opportunity, opportunitycontactrole, conga

I'm looking to see if there is any way to access the Account Fields (ie: Account_Billingaddress) associated with the Opportunity Contact Role from the Opportunity Object.

Opportunity->Opportunity Contact Role->Account

(Account details would be the account associated with Contact Role, not the Opportunities Account Information)

I've been able to get access to the Contact Role information with the below:

```
SELECT id, 
Contact.Account.Name, Role 
FROM OpportunityContactRole 
WHERE (OpportunityId = '{pv0}') AND (Role = 'Lawyer') LIMIT 1
```

But I need to access the address associated with the "Lawyers" Account and can not figure out how to access that data if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the address by something like this:

> SELECT id,  Contact.Account.Name, Contact.Account.BillingAddress, Role
> FROM OpportunityContactRole  WHERE (OpportunityId = '{pv0}') AND (Role
> = 'Lawyer') LIMIT 1